# ActiveRecord association: create new association or reference existing if associated attributes match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, unique-index

I have two models below.  They can be explained as follows:

A report has a report_detail (which determines start/end months).  Many reports can have the same report detail, but no two report details can be the same.

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr: name :: String
  # attr: report_detail_id :: Integer
  belongs_to :report_detail
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_detail
end

class ReportDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr: duration :: Integer
  # attr: starting_month :: Integer
  # attr: offset :: Integer
end
```

I have a unique constraint on an index on ReportDetail for [:duration, :starting_month, :offset]

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:  If a new Report has ReportDetail that has a unique combination attrs (:duration, :starting_month, :offset), create the new ReportDetail and save as normal.  If a report has a ReportDetail whereby an existing ReportDetail has the same attributes, associate the report's detail with this ReportDetail and save report.

I got this to work by aliasing the setter on `report_detail=` using a `ReportDetail.find_or_create_by...` but it's ugly (and it also creates unnecessary ReportDetail entries just by instantiating new Reports with the detail attributes, and for some reason i couldn't get the save to work properly using `.find_or_initialize_by...`).  I also tried a `before_save` on the ReportDetail to say, if I match something else, set `self` to that something else.  Apparently you can't set self like that.

Any thought on the best way to go about this?

**see [this gist](http://gist.github.com/579718) for my current setter overwrite with alias**

Comment: Can you post the code for aliasing the setter? Maybe as a gist and linking it here. It sounds like that was on the right track, but there may be a bug or two.

Comment: added...    there's no bug in this code, it all works, but I'm looking for a nicer solution.  My biggest beef is that it actually creates a ReporDetail when you initialize using the gist above.  I also couldn't get it to work properly with find_or_initialize_by as the save on the association is meant to happen before this, so it doesn't end up saving the association on the first go

Answer (score 1):

Just ran at this problem today, my solution was based to `object_attributes=` method, which is provided by accepts_nested_attributes_for, i think this creates less mess instead of overriding the standard association setter method. Dived into rails source a bit to find this solution, here's the [github link](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb#L168). The code:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr: name :: String
  # attr: report_detail_id :: Integer
  belongs_to :report_detail
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_detail

  def report_detail_attributes=(attributes)
    report_detail = ReportDetail.find_or_create_by_duration_and_display_duration_and_starting_month_and_period_offset(attrs[:duration],attrs[:display_duration],attrs[:starting_month],attrs[:period_offset])
    attributes[:id]=report_detail.id
    assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association(:report_detail, attributes)
  end
end
```

Some explanation, if you provide an id, will be considered as update, so no longer creates new objects. Also I know that this approach needs a query in plus, but i can't find a better solution for now.

Also, it seems like you have has_one association between report and report detail, if this is your case you might try this:

```
   class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
      # attr: name :: String
      # attr: report_detail_id :: Integer
      has_one :report_detail
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_detail, :update_only=>true
    end
```

Accoring to [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) this should work for you.
From rails3 documentation:

> :update_only
>
> Allows you to specify that an existing record may only be updated. A
> new record may only be created when
> there is no existing record. This
> option only works for one-to-one
> associations and is ignored for
> collection associations. This option
> is off by default.

Comment: sorry for not answering/accepting, i've switched over to something else, haven't had a chance to test, will update when I do, thx for the answer!